# Adding a hyperlink to an email generated through PowerShell

Tags: html, email, powershell, hyperlink

I have a script that currently does several things. It creates a user account in Active Directory, writes data to a SQL table and sends an email to the account requestor with the account's user name and password.

We'd love to add a hyperlink to that email so that the requestor can click to view their original request form, but I can't quite seem to get the syntax right.

Because double quotes are used in the PowerShell syntax as well as the HTML link, I defined the link as a variable and inserted that variable into the -body section of the email to eliminate double quote confusion, though this may not be necessary.

Can anyone help me insert a link in this email?
Many thanks!

CURRENT COPY:

```
"The user account you requested (request #$ReqID) has been created."
```

We'd like $ReqID to hyperlink to the Web form.

THE VARIABLE I'VE DEFINED:

```
$link = '<a href="http://tsturl/detail.aspx?reqID=$reqID">$ReqID</a>'
```

But it displays in the email body like this:

```
The user account you requested (request #<a href="http://tsturl/detail.aspx?reqID=$reqID">$ReqID</a>) has been created.
```

Help?

Comment: What code are your using to send the email? Are you using `System.Net.Mail`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap your quotes around, i.e.:

```
$link = "<a href='http://tsturl/detail.aspx?reqID=$reqID'>$ReqID</a>"
```

Or do:

```
$link = '<a href="http://tsturl/detail.aspx?reqID=$reqID">$ReqID</a>'
$link = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($link)
```

Further to your comment, if you want the mail body to render as HTML, an thus display a link, then you'll need to tell your mail client that the body is HTML. `$link` is just a plain old string and doesn't know that it's HTML.

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155012/mixing-sql-query-and-powershell-send-mailmessage), I'm guessing you're using the [Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet. If so then you need to specify the `-BodyAsHtml` switch.

Comment: Didn't work. It now displays

The user account you requested (request #<a href='http://tsturl/detail.aspx?reqID=5816'>5816</a>) has been created.

(Where 5816 was the request ID.)

Comment: @ColleenH218 - I've amended my answer.

Comment: @ColleenH218 - ah sorry, I thought you meant that the string interpolation wasn't working i.e. still showing `$reqID` and `$ReqID` in the html anchor rather than the value of `$reqID`. So really two problems?

Comment: No, it'll show the ReqID# value, but instead of '5678' becoming a hyperlink, it simply pastes in the hyperlink in long form. (It displays the "<a href....") I tried option #2 you listed and it's doing the same thing.

Comment: @ColleenH218 - even with specifying `-BodyAsHtml`? If so you may need to wrap the whole message in `<html><body> your stuff here </body></html>`. The first problem is solved (string interpolation), you now need to feed something to `Send-MailMessage` it can handle as HTML.

Comment: Oh geez. THAT was it. In one of my many revisions of this I had omitted the "BodyAsHTML". It's working well now.

Thanks so much for your help!