# PowerShell - Clickable Hyperlink

Tags: html, powershell, datatable

I am trying to create a clickable hyperlink in PowerShell for a report that is emailed. This hyperlink will live in a data table that is converted to HTML. I have tried a few different methods that I found on this site but none of them work.

```
$link = "<a href='https://www.example.com/report/20678/'>Report</a>"
```

This code is living in the data table and is converted to HTML. The column in the report that supposed to show the hyperlink just shows.

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/report/20678/'>Report</a>
```

The desired result would be a clickable "Report" in the column.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706312/adding-a-hyperlink-to-an-email-generated-through-powershell

Comment: Hi, yes that was the first one I tried. I even added. 

<html><body> your stuff here </body></html>

It still output The entire string, of if I pipe it to | ConvertTo-HTML after, it just shows "System.Object"